# campare a long variable with INT_MAX + 1

Tags: c++

```
//Code here
long a = 42;
if(a > INT_MAX + 1)
```

When I do this comparison, `a > INT_MAX + 1` actually returns true, which makes me confused.
The reason seems like `INT_MAX + 1` is overflowed. But Why? `INT_MAX` should be just a macro which defined by a constant like `2^32 - 1`, therefore `INT_MAX + 1` should be just another constant value `2^32`. And since `a` is long, then during compiling the compiler should also implicitly convert the `INT_MAX + 1` to long type, which should be longer than int and not be overflowed.

I cannot understand why it is actually overflowed.

Could anybody help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> therefore INT_MAX + 1 should be just another constant value

It is an arithmetic expression. More specifically, it is an addition operation. The addition overflows and behaviour of the program is undefined.

> therefore during compiling the compiler should also implicitly convert the INT_MAX + 1 to long type

It does. But the conversion of the result happens *after* the operation.

You can fix the expression by using `a - 1 > INT_MAX`. Although that also has a failure case when `A` is `LONG_MIN`. Another approach is to convert one of the operands of the addition to a larger type (if a larger type exists on the system).

Comment: so, `a != LONG_MIN && a - 1 > INT_MAX` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
(long long)INT_MAX + 1
```

In order to treat the values as 64-bit BEFORE the addition takes places, avoiding the overflow.

Keep in mind, `long` is 32-bit on some compilers (MSVC). `long long`, I believe, has a guaranty of at least 64.

Comment: It's redundant to apply this to both sides. (And still undefined on a system where `int` and `long long` are the same size)

Comment: @M.M True, but I'm unaware of any (modern) systems where `int` and `long long` are the same.

Answer (score 1):

`INT_MAX + 1` is evaluated as an `int` before the comparison. It overflows and causes undefined behavior. Some implementations evaluate it to be -1 using wrap around logic. In some cases, that can be useful. You can read more about it at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow.

If `sizeof(long)` is greater than `sizeof(int)` on your platform, you can get the expected result by using

```
if(a > INT_MAX + 1L)
```

Answer (score 0):

the only thing you will have to do is just create another variable of type long and add 1 after that. here is the code for that:

```
    long a = 42;
    long b = INT_MAX;
    b = b + 1;
    if(a > b){
        cout<<"long greater"<<b;
    }
```